# I lose my session with PHP

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with a project I'm working on. I'm trying to code a simply login system using PHP + Sessions. But I lose my session, and I don't really know why, the code:

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['logedin'] == True)){
    <form action = "login.php" method = "post" id="login-form" class = "login-form">
        <input type = "text" name = "username" maxlength = "100"/>
        <input type = "password" maxlength = "50" name = "password"/>

        <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
}else{
   echo "Loged in.";
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(!isset($_SESSION['logedin'] == True)){
        if($username == 'username' && $password == 'password'){
                    $_SESSION['logedin'] = True;
                    header("index.php"); // Loged in
        }
    }
?>
```

The real code is not this one, because it's too long to put here, but this is a simply resume about the code... I'm losing my head, because if I open a session into index.php, it works, but if I go out of my page (in this case, login.php through form), when I back to index, session just vanish...

I got to say I don't use any frameworks or something, it's a simply form, all done with PHP.

Comment: Be careful, you're spelling `loggedin` as `logedin` - just make sure they're the same everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Your parens on the first line are going to be a problem:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logedin'] == True)){
```

Change to:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logedin'])) {
```

Why are you doing a double negative on this condition?  Instead of doing `!isset == true`, just do `isset == false`.  This is just likely to add confusion to your code, and the more intuitive (and simplistic) your code, the better.

In your login.php you also have that line:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logedin'] == True)){
```

You are basically saying `isset(true) == false` which should always return false.  Because `$_SESSION['logedin'] == true` is true.  Change it to `if (isset($_SESSION['logedin']))` which will be true if you're logged in.

Let's break this condition down a little further to see what you're doing

```
if (false == isset(
 $_SESSION['loged'] == true  // will be true if you're logged in
 )  // isset will return true, but you're expecting a false
)
```

Your isset is always going to return true.  Whether $_SESSION['logedin'] == true returns true or false it will be "isset".  Isset will only return false if the return value is null or the var does not exist.  "False" is a value and exists.  Does that make sense?  Sorry if this is confusing.  Basically, don't use conditions in your isset! :).  Use the isset as a part of a condition, but don't pass them into the isset parameter.

Comment: Can I borrow your eyes? :)

Comment: My bad, I wrote it wrong. The current code are like you are saying, with single equal.

Comment: Isn't `if(!isset($_SESSION['logedin']) == true){` pretty redundant? What about `if(!isset($_SESSION['logedin'])){`?

Comment: @elusive it is, I addressed that as an edit to my answer.  I think the last part of my answer is the major problem in his code though...